# Default options in custom memoir class

Tags: memoir, documentclass-writing, class-options

I can't get default arguments to work with my custom class based on `memoir`. I want to be able to define some default options (`a4paper`,`danish`) but I want to be able to override them when I call `\documentclass` in the tex document. How can I resolve this?

PS: I deleted a similar earlier question because the reason for the problem was a trivial syntax error. This is not the case here, though.

*testclass.cls*

```
% identification
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2013/12/02 testclass]

% declaration of options
\DeclareOption{danish}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{danish}{babel}}

\DeclareOption{english}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}}

\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}

\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,danish}

% execution of options
\ProcessOptions

% package loading
\LoadClass{memoir}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

% main code
\@ifpackagewith{babel}{danish}{%
  \renewcommand\danishhyphenmins{22}}

%\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{*}{1}
%\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1}
%\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

\makepagestyle{testclass}
\makeoddhead{testclass}{\@author}{}{\today}
\makeheadrule{testclass}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeoddfoot{testclass}{}{\thepage / \pageref{Lastpage}}{}
\pagestyle{testclass}
```

*test.tex*

```
\documentclass{testclass}
\author{name}
\begin{document}
\section*{Test}
\subsection*{a}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's never a good idea to load `babel` in the class, because this has the consequence that no other language can be used unless one has the awkward code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{lsorbian}{babel}
\documentclass{testclass}
```

However, the problem is that global options are always processed first when a package is loaded. So, if you say

```
\documentclass[english]{testclass}
```

the default `danish` option will be processed after `english` and so the main document language will be Danish in any case.

Instead of executing `danish` as default option, you can do in a different way:

```
% identification
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2013/12/02 testclass]

% declaration of options
\newif\ifdext@languagechosen

\DeclareOption{english}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
  \dext@languagechosentrue
}
\DeclareOption{danish}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{danish}{babel}
  \dext@languagechosentrue
}

\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}

\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{memoir}

% execution of options
\ProcessOptions

% package loading
\LoadClass{memoir}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ifdext@languagechosen
  \RequirePackage{babel}
\else
  \RequirePackage[danish]{babel}
\fi
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

% main code
\@ifpackagewith{babel}{danish}{%
  \renewcommand\danishhyphenmins{22}}

%\setlrmarginsandblock{4cm}{*}{1}
%\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1}
%\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

\makepagestyle{testclass}
\makeoddhead{testclass}{\@author}{}{\today}
\makeheadrule{testclass}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeoddfoot{testclass}{}{\thepage / \pageref{Lastpage}}{}
\pagestyle{testclass}
```

So if you load `testclass` with no language option, Danish will be the main (and only available) language. Here are the other possibilities:

- `\documentclass[danish]{testclass}`: main (and only) language Danish
- `\documentclass[english]{testclass}`: main (and only) language English
- `\documentclass[english,danish]{testclass}`: main language Danish
- `\documentclass[danish,english]{testclass}`: main language English

But, again, I'd not force users to such a limited choice, preferring to warn them if `babel` has not been loaded in the document. The setting of the hyphenation minima can be done with

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackagewith{babel}{danish}{%
    \renewcommand\danishhyphenmins{22}}%
}
```

However this *is* the default for Danish, according to `danish.ldf`, so this setting is redundant.

Note also the different way to set A4 paper, because the default `letterpaper` option in `memoir` would override it.

Comment: So to set the paperformat to a4paper default, I would have to use another \newif ?

Comment: @dexterity Use `\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{memoir}`, I'll edit the answer